# Escape question mark in VSCode launch.json file argument

Tags: visual-studio-code, escaping

I am trying to launch my program using VSCode launch.json; however it seems that passing special characters as argument in launch.json lead to json processing errors.

In my case:

```
"name": "Python: Current File",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "vmware.py", "args": ["--api-user=MyUser", "--api-pass=My(SpecialP?ss"],
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"justMyCode": false
```

Apparently, the problem is caused by the question mark which I have tried to escape it, but without success.

This gives me "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect":

```
"--api-pass='My(SpecialP?ss'"
```

This completely "hides" the question mark from the what is being sent to my script:

```
"--api-pass=My(SpecialP?ss"
```

How can be the question mark properly escaped?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use internalConsole instead of integratedTerminal.

[How do I pass an argument with special characters from launch.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908278/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-with-special-characters-from-launch-json)